# A pixel can be rectangle or it must be always a square?

Tags: android

I have a circle image, but I am using it on android devices on some devices its not perfectly circle. I have one doubt a pixel is a square always or can be rectangle, depending on device. If so how to handle this since circle image has same number of pixel in width and height.

Comment: probably the device's screen that shows the ill circle has a low screen resolution, so big pixels.

Comment: Yes, its low screen resolution device. I also noticed that the physical height width of the device measuring using scale is different what it should be if pixel would be square. So pixel can be rectangular if I am not wrong.

Comment: I don't think that there is much you can do to improve your circle if the resolution is low. What would you do to improve the quality if you have a way to know if it's a square or not? It will have sharp corners anyway. Am I right?

Comment: @Math - the issue here is one of aspect ratio, not just the pixelization inherent in a low resolution.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct, a pixel is not always square. It depends on the screen, and how many dots per inch (DPI) it has in each direction.

If you know the exact size of the screen in "real" dimensions (mm, etc), you can scale it appropriately, but there's no way that I know of to find this at runtime.